# How to define Ubuntu sudoer permission for specific set of commands

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, foreman, sudoers

To allow my Rails application run upstart commands via the Foreman gem, I resorted to providing sudoer definition like below for a specific user. Is there a variation of the sudoers definition where I can provide a list of linux commands for passwordless sudo authorization?

My current sudoer definition is `bill ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL`

This allows user 'bill' to run any privileged commands without any password. How can I restrict 'bill' to only run the following commands via sudo w/o password?

```
sudo service rails_app stop
sudo service rails_app start
sudo service rails_app restart
```

I tried the following definition, but received syntax error when saving the visudo edit.

```
bill localhost=(service rails_app stop, service rails_app start, service rails_app restart) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest file would be:

```
bill ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/service rails_app stop
bill ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/service rails_app start
bill ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/service rails_app restart
```